# How to Access User "Sent" Mail Box using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'd like to get the details of messages that was sent across by some User X. I am able to get the messages that were received by this User X using Graph API and the environment is well set up.

I am looking for some endpoint (Graph API) that gets me the details of "Sent Items" for this User X. Is there any endpoint provided or any workaround for the same?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get messages from the SentItems folder of a Mailbox using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@domain.com')/mailfolders('sentitems')/messages
```